# Using rpmbuild in Python

Tags: python, rpmbuild

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to write a python script to build rpm packages as part of an automated build system (Hudson).

I'm looking at the rpm-python API but I can't seem to see anything that relates to rpmbuild.

Am I missing something or is there no way to build an rpm package through the rpm api's? I was hoping I wouldn't have to call rpmbuild from the shell because the build process involves different platforms such as Solaris, and I wanted the script to be portable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian includes python bindings for rpm allowing you to use rpm from python scripts

http://packages.debian.org/stable/python/python-rpm

Also checkout : 
[API Documentation](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/index.html)

[RPM Python bindings - presentation and tutorial](http://rpm.org/wiki/Docs#PackagerDocumentation)

Comment: I've looked at the above documentation but it seems that the python-rpm bindings provides methods to query the database and install/upgrade rpms, but doesn't actually build rpms.

Does this mean I have to call rpmbuild from my script directly?

eg. subprocess.Popen('rpmbuild -ba rpm.spec', shell=True)

Comment: Yes, for building rpms, rpmbuild is the only avenue.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses `distutils`, it is as simple as `./setup.py bdist_rpm` [More info](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html) on the Python docs page for `distutils`.